# What form must this function in this integral take?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fluid-dynamics

I'm working on a 2D fluid simulation based on Stokes flow.  A point disturbance in the fluid at $(r, \phi)$ (polar coordinates) of $F$ can be cancelled at the surface of a circle of radius $R > r$ by smearing point disturbances of various strengths around the perimeter of the circle.  I'm trying to determine what these point disturbances are at different points on the circle.  Mathematically this looks like solving for $f(t)$ in this integral:

$$2 \int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta + t) (\frac{1}{2} -\ln(2 R \sin\frac{t}{2})) + \overline{f(\theta + t)} e^{i (2 \theta + t)} dt
\\= F (1-\ln(r^2 + R^2 - 2 r R \cos(\theta - \phi))) + \overline{F}\frac{r e^{i \phi} - R e^{i \theta}}{r e^{-i \phi} - R e^{-i \theta}}  $$

for $\phi, \theta, t, r, R \in \mathbb{R}, F \in \mathbb{C}, 0 \le r < R, f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, and $\overline{F}$ is the complex conjugate of $F$.

I'm trying to determine roughly what $f(t)$ looks like, though I don't necessarily need the exact function.  For instance, empirically I know when $r = 0$, $f(t) = a e^{i (2t + \psi)} + z$ for some unknown $a, \psi \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}$.

However I have no idea how to even begin generalizing that when $r \ne 0$.  Any help getting pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\phi$? A fixed value? It doesn't occur on the LHS side, but is on the right. If it isn't constant, then the equation can't hold for all $\phi$. $F$ is a function, but $\overline F$ has no argument, or is the following fractional expression supposed to be an argument?

Comment: $\phi$ is constant.  It's part of the polar location of the point disturbance in the fluid.  Apologies for my slight mixing of terms, but $f$ is a function and $F$ is a constant complex value, and they don't have anything to do with each other except that they're both forces physically.  The problems of having too many unknowns and running out of available characters :)

Comment: Okay. I saw the $F(...)$ and mistook that for a functional notation, rather than a scalar multiplication.

Comment: By trig identities and making use of the periodicity of $f$, the integral can be rewritten as $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\left[1-\ln\left(2R^2(1-\cos(t-\theta))\right)\right]+\overline{f(t)}2e^{i(\theta+t)}\,dt$$ which may be useful.